# Menu total index counts, length of menu items

Tags: python, menu, tkinter

I have created a `Menu`:

```
self.commandMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
self.commandMenu.add_command(label = "Rename", accelerator = "Ctrl+R", command = self.onRename, state = "disabled")
self.commandMenu.add_command(label = "Edit module name", command = self.onEditModuleName, state = "disabled")
self.commandMenu.add_command(label = "Create instance", command = self.onCreateInstance, state = "disabled")
self.commandMenu.add_command(label = "Delete instance", command = self.onDeleteInstance, state = "disabled")
```

I plan on configuring all of its items sometime later, but the following code configures 1 item at a time:

```
self.commandMenu.entryconfig(1, state = "normal")
```

Is there a way to obtain the total amount of menu items, or configure all items at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `self.commandMenu.index("end")` to get the index of the last item in the menu. You can then iterate over the items to configure them all:

```
last = self.commandMenu.index("end")
for i in range(last+1):
    self.commandMenu.entryconfigure(i, state="normal")
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan! Would you also take a look at some of my other Tkinter questions?

Answer (score 2):

[Updating the answer of Bryan Oakley]

`self.commandMenu.index("end")` won't work.
Use `self.commandMenu.index(tk.END)` instead.

[EDIT]
Make sure to catch error when the menu has no element : `index(tk.END)` will return `None` and you will have an error `Cannot add int and NoneType.`