# Python tkinter: Getting the number of entries in an OptionMenu dropdown list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The function below creates a nicely formatted list of all attributes of an OptionMenu widget.  However a kludge is needed because OptionMenu does *not* having a "Menu size"' attribute (that holds the number of elements inside the dropdown list).

How do I extract this value from the widget so I can eliminate the kludge (and show the attributes of EVERY entry in the drop-down menu) ?

BTW, The function does not list the contents of the (non-standard) Optionmenu "command" option.  For info on this option see the accepted answer to [tkinter OptionMenu issue (bug?): GUI and program values not kept in lockstep (python 3.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360766/tkinter-optionmenu-issue-bug-gui-and-program-values-not-kept-in-lockstep-py?answertab=active#tab-top) )

```python
def OptionMenuConfigLister( OptionMenuWidget ) : 
    ''' 
       Uncomment this block to see ALL attributes of the widget
    #
    # Gets the main attributes of the widget (EXCLUDING the attributes for 
    # the  dropdown list and the values in the list)      
    #
    print( " \nOptionMenuWidget.config()\n"  )
    for i, j in enumerate( sorted( OptionMenuWidget.config().items() ) ) :
        print( "   {0:<19} |{1}|".format( j[ 0 ], j[ 1 ][ -1 ] ), flush = True )     
    #
    # Gets the attributes of the list portion of the widget (but NOT the entries)   
    #
    print( "\nOptionMenuWidget[ 'menu' ].config().items() :\n" ) 
    for i, j in enumerate( sorted( OptionMenuWidget[ 'menu' ].config().items() ) ) :
        print( "   {0:<18} |{1}|".format( j[ 0 ], j[ 1 ][ -1 ] ), flush = True ) 
    '''
    #
    # Get the attributes of each/every entry in the dropdown list
    #
    # TODO: Determine how to get # of items in list          
    #
    for i in range( 0, 1 ) :  ''' <======== KLUDGE '''

        print( "\nOptionMenuWidget[ 'menu' ].entryconfig(" + str( i ) + ").items()) :\n" )
        for _, j in  enumerate( sorted(  
                    OptionMenuWidget[ 'menu' ].entryconfig( i ).items() ) ) :
            print( "   {0:<16} |{1}|".format( j[ 0 ], j[ 1 ][ -1 ] ), flush = True )
        print()     
    return
```

EDIT 20180117:  Here's the fix, based on the answer by @nae - replace the kludge line with:

```
ElementCount = OptionMenuWidget[ 'menu' ].index( 'end' ) + 1
for i in range( 0, ElementCount ) :
```

And as per comment by @furas, sample code now uses [ -1 ] in the formatted print statements.

Comment: Couldn't you just count? Or use the len?

Comment: can't you use `[-1]` instead of `[-1:][0]` ?

Comment: @furas: Yes. The only purpose for [0] is to print the value cleanly, e,g. without it you get  |( "ABC", )| .  With it you get  |ABC |.  (Note that | represents the start/end of the printed string.)  It's only a matter of personal taste, try it both ways.

Comment: Just noticed a typo in the above comment.  |ABC | should read |ABC| , i.e. no trailing blank.

Comment: I'm talking about `:` in `[-1:]` - what do you get if you use `[-1]` without `:` (and without `[0]`) ?

Comment: @furas: Good catch! Both produce |ABC|.  Use of [-1:][0] is/was a historical artifact, the simpler [-1] is all that's needed.  (When you think about it [-1:][0] returns the same value as [-1]).  I'm going to replace all occurances in my code with [-1]. My thanks for pointing out this simplifciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Menu total index counts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22973347/7032856) and from the source code, the fact that `OptionMenu`'s `*values` are stored as `Menu` items:

```
class OptionMenu(Menubutton):
    """OptionMenu which allows the user to select a value from a menu."""
    def __init__(self, master, variable, value, *values, **kwargs):

        ...

        menu.add_command(label=value,
                 command=_setit(variable, value, callback))
        for v in values:
            menu.add_command(label=v,
                     command=_setit(variable, v, callback))
        self["menu"] = menu
```

One can extract the *'Menu Size'* using `.index('end')` for `OptionMenu`'s menu option like the following:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

opt_var = tk.IntVar()
opt = tk.OptionMenu(root, opt_var, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4)
opt.pack()

print(opt['menu'].index('end') + 1) # basically len(*values) + len(value)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is the answer as I understand the question which I think is unclear in its current state.

Comment: I think I understand the question the same way and it is the answer.

Comment: @Nae: It worked like a charm. Just another case of woeful tkinter documentation, I knew it had to be something simple but couldn't find this method/trick anyhere.  Thanks.